# Django ajax post method dont redirect

Tags: json, django, ajax, redirect, post

im following a tuto on how ajax work on Django, its my first time with ajax and im facing a little problem ,the data insertion is working but the success ajax dont redirect corectly, and thank you for the help
this the code

views.py :

```
class exo(View):
def get(self, request):


    form = ExerciseForm()
    tasks = task.objects.all()
    context = {
                   'form': form,
                   'tasks': tasks
                   }
    return render(request, 'coach/test.html', 
    context=context)

def post(self, request):

    form = ExerciseForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExerciseForm(request.POST)
        print(form)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('adding task', form)
            new_exrercise = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(new_exrercise)}, status=200 )
        else:
            print('not adding task')
            return redirect('exo')
```

ajax function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#addExercise").click(function() {
    var serializedData = $("#TaskForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({ 
               url: $("TaskForm").data('url'),
               data : serializedData,
               type: 'post',
               success: function(response) {
                    $("#taskList").append('<div 
class="card"><div class="card-body">'+ response.task.name 
+'<button type="button" class="close float-right"> <span 
aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>');
                    
               }
           })
  });

});
```

html content :

```
 <form class="submit-form" method="post" id="TaskForm" 
data-url="{% url 'session' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
    {% for field in form %}
    <div style="margin-bottom: 2rem;"></div>
    

        {{field}}
    
    
    {%  endfor %}
    <div style="margin-bottom: 2rem;"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle " id="addExercise">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is what i get (i get an object and nothing else )
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWitc.png)

when i comeback to the page exo the insertion is done
and the console show me that the post is sending well :
[21/Dec/2020 22:25:38] "POST /coach/exo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 43

Comment: Your `addExercise` button will *first* submit the form, since that form means you make a POST request and you thus load a new page, it will *never* perform the AJAX request, you should change the `<button type="">` to just a generic button, so drop the `type="submit"`.

Comment: thanks , i did it and it wasnt posting anymore , until i switch from a view to a function i dont know why , but its working good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle " id="addExercise">Confirm</button>
```

will *submit* the form, and not (only) by the AJAX call, but simply by the fact that you made it a submit button. This thus means that the browser will encode the form and make a POST request with that form, and then the browser will render the response.

You thus should remove the `type="submit"` part from the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle " id="addExercise">Confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove the submit type and nothing was working , the button wasnt posting anything to ajax then i switch my view class into a function and it work i really dont know why there is the view

```
def addsession(request):

    template = loader.get_template('coach/addexercise.html')
    exercises = exercise.objects.all()
    # context = {'exercises': exercises}
    UpperBody = exercise.objects.filter(category__name="Upper Body")
    LowerBody = exercise.objects.filter(category__name="Lower Body")
    FIIT = exercise.objects.filter(category__name="FIIT")
    LIIT = exercise.objects.filter(category__name="LIIT")
    form = ExerciseForm()
    tasks = task.objects.all()
    context = {'exercises': exercises,
                   'UpperBody': UpperBody,
                   'LowerBody': LowerBody,
                   'FIIT': FIIT,
                   'LIIT': LIIT,
                   'form': form,
                   'tasks': tasks
                   }




    form = ExerciseForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExerciseForm(request.POST)
        print(form)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('adding task', form)
            new_exrercise = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(new_exrercise)}, status=200 )
        else:
            print('not adding task')
            return redirect('session')

    return render(request, 'coach/addexercise.html', context=context)
```

and thank u guys for your answers i really didnt give attention to the input type of button